# Abstract Method Error In GraphLoader Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I have created a simple project in `Graphx`, as soon as I am trying to run this test project, I am getting `AbstractMethodError`, error is comming inside this method `edgeListFile`, looks like something related to logger which I am not abe to see, Please help.

Here is my `.scala file`

```
object graphtest extends App  {

  import org.apache.spark.graphx.{GraphLoader, VertexId}

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("learning spark").getOrCreate
    val sc = spark.sparkContext


    val graph1 = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(spark.sparkContext, "E:\\code\\Cit-HepTh.txt")
    val res: (VertexId, Int) = graph1.inDegrees.reduce((a, b) => if (a._2 > b._2) a else b)

graph1.edges.collect().take(10).foreach(println)

}
```

Here is my `build.sbt` file

```
name := "myproject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("myproject.Processor")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % Test,
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.1"
)
```

and finally the complete failed stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError
at                 org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$.initializeLogIfNecessary(GraphLoader.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$.log(GraphLoader.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging$class.logInfo(Logging.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$.logInfo(GraphLoader.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader$.edgeListFile(GraphLoader.scala:96)
at aaa.graphtest$.delayedEndpoint$zettasense$graphtest$1(Test.scala:15)
at aaa.graphtest$delayedInit$body.apply(Test.scala:6)
at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
at aaa.graphtest$.main(Test.scala:6)
at aaa.graphtest.main(Test.scala)
```

Comment: [GraphX is a separate dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx).

Comment: Also "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.0.1" may be problematic as the version is different from the one used by spark-core. I'd update it to be 2.3.1 as the rest of Spark libs.

Answer (score 0):

It was a library mismatch, I updated `spark-core`, `spark-sql`, `spark-mlib` to the latest version and it worked smoothly, here is how my `build.sbt` looks now

```
name := "myproject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

mainClass in(Compile, packageBin) := Some("myproject.Processor")


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.0-SNAP10" % Test,
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.4.0"
)
```